# Pass value from a button to a parameter in a function or to a variable

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, addeventlistener

im trying to make this "rock, paper, scissors" work using buttons.

I'm trying two different ways but i dont know how to achieve it:

1st way: Pass to the parameter`playerSelection` in `function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection` the correct parameter when we click on the buttons in the html

or

2nd way: Pass to variable `var playerSelection` inside `function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection` the correct value when we click on the buttons in the html.

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let optionsList = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  let option = optionsList[Math.floor(Math.random() * optionsList.length)];
  return option
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  var playerSelection = ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
    var computerSelection = computerPlay();

  if (playerSelection = "rock") {
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case "rock":
        return "T";
      case "paper":
        return "M";
      case "scissors":
        return "Y";
    }
  } else if (playerSelection = "paper") {
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case "rock":
        return "Y";
      case "paper":
        return "T";
      case "scissors":
        return "M";
    }
  } else if (playerSelection = "scissors") {
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case "rock":
        return "M";
      case "paper":
        return "Y";
      case "scissors":
        return "T";
    }
  }
}

function playGame() {
  let i = 0
  for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    let outcome = playRound()
    if (outcome == "M") {
      console.log("Machine Wins");
    } else if (outcome == "Y") {
      console.log("You Win")
    } else if (outcome == "T") {
      console.log("Tie, try again")
    }
  }
}

let rockButton = document.querySelector("#rock");
let paperButton = document.querySelector("#paper");
let scissorsButton = document.querySelector("scissors");

rockButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  playRound("rock")
});
paperButton = addEventListener("click", function() {
  playRound("paper")
});
scissorsButton = addEventListener("click", function() {
  playRound("scissors")
});


let playButton = document.querySelector("#play")
playButton.addEventListener("click", playGame)
```

```html
<title>ROCK PAPER SCISSORS</title>
<script src="/rock_paper_scissors.js" async></script>

<div class="buttons">
  <button id="rock">ROCK</button>
  <button id="paper">PAPER</button>
  <button id="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="play">PLAY!</button>
</div>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Start by moving the script to AFTER the last div, since you declare your variables from the rendered HTML and they need to exist before you use them

Comment: Alternatively wrap the bottom part of your script starting with `let rockButton` in a load event listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want something more like this

I use an array to count

```js
function computerPlay() {
  let optionsList = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  let option = optionsList[Math.floor(Math.random() * optionsList.length)];
  return option
}

function playRound(playerSelection) {
  var computerSelection = computerPlay();

  if (playerSelection = "rock") {
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case "rock":
        return "T"; 
      case "paper":
        return "M";
      case "scissors":
        return "Y";
    }
  } else if (playerSelection = "paper") {
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case "rock":
        return "Y";
      case "paper":
        return "T";
      case "scissors":
        return "M";
    }
  } else if (playerSelection = "scissors") {
    switch (computerSelection) {
      case "rock":
        return "M";
      case "paper":
        return "Y";
      case "scissors":
        return "T";
    }
  }
}

let cnt = 0, results = []; 
function playGame() {
  document.querySelector(".buttons").classList.remove("hide");
  document.getElementById("results").textContent = "";
  cnt= 0;
  results = [];
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const result = document.getElementById("results");
  document.querySelector(".buttons").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    const outcome = playRound(e.target.id.slice(1))
    let text;
    if (outcome == "M") {
      text = "Machine Wins";
    } else if (outcome == "Y") {
      text = "You Win"
    } else if (outcome == "T") {
      text  = "Tie, try again"
    }
    results.push(outcome)
    results.sort();
    if (results.length === 3) {
      const final = results.toString();
      if (final.startsWith("YY")) text = "You won the match"
      else if (final.startsWith("MM")) text = "The computer won the match"
      else text = "You tied";
      document.querySelector(".buttons").classList.add("hide");
    }
    result.innerHTML = text;
    
  });
  
  document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", playGame)
})
```

```css
.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<title>ROCK PAPER SCISSORS</title>
<script src="/rock_paper_scissors.js" async></script>
<div>
  <button id="play">PLAY!</button>
</div>

<div class="buttons hide">
  <button id="rock">ROCK</button>
  <button id="paper">PAPER</button>
  <button id="scissors">SCISSORS</button>
</div>

<div id="results"></div>
```